# No output on clicking <button> linked to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Following is the code: I cannot find the mistake

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Party Sequence</title>
</head>
<body>

<label for="inputN">Enter the value of n:</label>
<input type="number" id="inputN" min="1" step="1" value="1">
<button onclick="result2(number)">Calculate</button>
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
  number=document.getElementById("inputN").value;
    function result2(number)
    {
      return (number-1)**(number-2);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Result: "+ result2(number);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried removing the (number) argument of function yet shows nothing on clicking the button.

Comment: Your function returns before you update the result's innerHTML.

Comment: You are reading the value of the input before anything is entered.

Comment: But also keep an eye on your dev log; why are you calling the function recursively? There's no base case to the recursion.

Comment: @mykaf What to do then

Comment: First, I don't think your function needs to return anything. Just update the innerHTML. But did you intend to call `result2()` recursively? It seems like you just want to append the result of your calculation, so just do that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code, it seems like you are trying to perform button click action using Javascript, and I noticed that you are trying to access "number" variable from Javascript on HTML. But we are unable to use javascript variables directly on HTML, So we can directly define the number on the javascript result2() function instead of passing arguments, and also you have to put the return on last.
the code might look like,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Party Sequence</title>
</head>
<body>

<label for="inputN">Enter the value of n:</label>
<input type="number" id="inputN" min="1" step="1" value="1">
<button onclick="result2()">Calculate</button>
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
  function result2() {
    var number = document.getElementById("inputN").value;
    var result = (number - 1) ** (number - 2);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + result;
    return result
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Party Sequence</title>
</head>
<body>

<label for="inputN">Enter the value of n:</label>
<input type="number" id="inputN" min="1" step="1" value="1">

<button onclick="calculateResult()">Calculate</button>

<!-- Placeholder element to display the result -->
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
// Function to calculate (number - 1)^(number - 2)
function calculateResult() {
    // Read the value of 'n' from the input field
    var number = document.getElementById("inputN").value;
    // Calculate (number - 1)^(number - 2)
    var result = Math.pow((number - 1), (number - 2));
    // Insert the result into the HTML element with ID 'result'
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good answers include some explanation, not just code.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `return`, the function exits and no code after `return` runs. Try adding `return` at the end of the function instead.